# how to call jquery pnotify only once during web form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Hello i am trying to call `pnotify` in my asp.net web form. It is running properly but when i refresh my page it show me that same notify again...

So anyone can please help me from this issue and here is my code:

```
function successMessage() {

    new PNotify({

        title: "Success",
        text: "Login Successfully",
        width: "100%",
        timeout:'100',
        cornerclass: "no-border-radius",
        addclass: "stack-custom-top bg-primary",
        type: 'success',

    });
}
```

Comment: Please tell more detail !

Answer (score 1):

You can add `loggedIn` boolean variable to cooike with false value and then check this variable's value when page is loading. On page loading you must check this value, if it is false then you must call `successMessage()` and set this variable's value to `true` else doesn't call the function:

```
var checkLoggedIn = function(){
  var loggedIn = getCooike("loggedIn");

  if(!loggedIn){
    successMessage();
    setCooike("loggedIn", true);
  }
}

function successMessage() {    
        new PNotify({
          title: "Success",
          text: "Login Successfully",
          width: "100%",
          timeout:'100',
          cornerclass: "no-border-radius",
            addclass: "stack-custom-top bg-primary",
            type: 'success'   
       });
}

window.onload = checkLoggedIn;
```

I wrote `getCooike` and `setCooike` methods in my code. You can implement this methods using [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)